# Conversion of lidar data (.las) to binary lidar data (.bin) format (Kitti dataset format)

Tags: 3d, data-conversion, point-clouds, lidar

I have a .las file (lidar data) obtained from **high-speed phase-based laser scanner**. So the problem is most algorithms for object detection in 3D point cloud work on the .bin(Kitti dataset format) file. I wanted to know if this conversion can be achieved.